# interface cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have been stuck on this for 2 days and I need some help. I am using Unity.Mvc5 package for DI. I have the ITest interface which is registered in the bootstrapper. But when I try to access the Class constrcutor it throws the below error. At the same time, in quick watch, if I tried to resolve the interface using container.Resolve(), it shows the correct value.  Any idea what might be wrong?

I am not doing anything fancy. I have done this before and didn't face any issue. 
See the code snippet below

```
public interface ITest
{
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public Test()
    {
        string test = "";
    }
 }

// DI registration
var container = new UnityContainer();   
container.RegisterType<ITest, Test>();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

// Home controller
public HomeController(ITest test)
{             
    this.test = test;
}
```

The current type, Web.ITest, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The current type, Web.ITest, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The current type, Web.ITest, is an
>   interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?] 
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext
>   context) +176    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +24
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +39
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +27
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +209
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +183
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey) +106
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext
>   context) +68    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +126
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +39
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +27
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +209
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +183
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +165
>
> [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = "HomeController", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Web.ITest, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing
>   a type mapping?

Comment: UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); is called in application_start?

Comment: Yes. The registration call is happening. Even I can see the object when I user container.Resolve<ITest>